# JEST issue - Wired Get Rec

Tags: lwc-jest

I am writing a Jest to test Wire adapter

```
    import { createElement } from 'lwc';
import NtnxMWDRequest from 'c/ntnxMWDRequest';
import { registerLdsTestWireAdapter } from '@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest';
import { getRecord ,getFieldValue} from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import getAssetDetails from '@salesforce/apex/NtnxMWDRequestController.getAssetDetails';
import getSalesOrderLineDetails from '@salesforce/apex/NtnxMWDRequestController.getSalesOrderLines';
import processMWDRequest from '@salesforce/apex/NtnxMWDRequestController.createMWDRequest';

const mockGetSORecord = require('./data/getSORecord.json');
const mockGetAssetRecord = require('./data/getAssetRecord.json');
const mockGetSOLineRecord = require('./data/getSOLineRecord.json');

const getRecordWireAdapter = registerLdsTestWireAdapter(getRecord);
const getRecordWireAdapter_Asset = registerLdsTestWireAdapter(getAssetDetails);
const getRecordWireAdapter_SOLine = registerLdsTestWireAdapter(getSalesOrderLineDetails);

describe('c-ntnx-m-w-d-request', () => {
    afterEach(() => {
        // The jsdom instance is shared across test cases in a single file so reset the DOM
        while (document.body.firstChild) {
            document.body.removeChild(document.body.firstChild);
        }
    });


    it('TODO: test case generated by CLI command, please fill in test logic', () => {
        const element = createElement('c-ntnx-m-w-d-request', {
            is: NtnxMWDRequest
        });
     //   element.recordId='aBQ0q000000H7kOGAS';
     getRecordWireAdapter.emit(mockGetSORecord);
     document.body.appendChild(element);
        
        return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
             const order_Element = element.shadowRoot.querySelector("[data-id='SO_Name']");
             const orderValue = mockGetSORecord.fields.Name;
             expect(order_Element.textContent).toBe('${orderValue}');
 
        });
    });
});
```

I have supplied the data as JSON file - getSORecord.
I am trying to test SO-name value. While my getter is being fired in my controller, the 'order_Element' innerText/innerHTML always returns null. Though the element is rendered in Jest DOM, which means {soRecord} itself is populated.

```
<template if:true={soRecord}>
                    <lightning-layout vertical-align='center' multiple-rows>
                        <lightning-layout-item size="6">
                            <span class="slds-form-element slds-form-element_horizontal">
                                <span class="slds-form-element__label">
                                    <span>End User</span>
                                    <c-ntnx-generic-help-text content="End user for this sales order"></c-ntnx-generic-help-text>
                                </span>
                                <div  class="slds-form-element__control">
                                    <lightning-formatted-url label={endUserName} value={endUserLink} data-id='end-user'></lightning-formatted-url>
                                 </div>
                            </span>
                        </lightning-layout-item>
                        <lightning-layout-item size="6">
                            <span class="slds-form-element slds-form-element_horizontal">
                                <span class="slds-form-element__label">SalesOrder Name</span>
                                <div  class="slds-form-element__control">
                                    <lightning-formatted-text data-id='SO_Name' value={salesOrderName}></lightning-formatted-text>
                                </div>
                                
                            </span>
                        </lightning-layout-item>
                    </lightning-layout>
                 </template>
```

Controller:

```
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: SALES_ORDER_FIELDS })
    getSalesOrder({ error, data }) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('error', JSON.stringify(error));
        } else {
            if (data) {
                this.soRecord = data;
                //console.log('Data SO', JSON.stringify(this.soRecord));
            }
        }
    }

get salesOrderName() {
        //console.log('getter fired',getFieldValue(this.soRecord, NAME_FIELD));
        return getFieldValue(this.soRecord, NAME_FIELD);
    }
```

The error I am getting is:

```
c-ntnx-m-w-d-request › TODO: test case generated by CLI command, please fill in test logic

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: "${orderValue}"
    Received: ""

      35 |             const order_Element = element.shadowRoot.querySelector("[data-id='SO_Name']");
      36 |             const orderValue = mockGetSORecord.fields.Name;
    > 37 |             expect(order_Element.textContent).toBe('${orderValue}');
         |             ^
      38 |  
      39 |         });
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two potential issues here.

1. The test is using a stub for `<lightning-formatted-text>`, which isn't actually rendering anything even though the value is being successfully passed in. Instead of verifying the `textContent` in the test, try grabbing the `value` property and verify it's set.
2. There may be a timing issue with getting the DOM to rerender. Instead of returning a Promise in the test, try waiting a macrotask by using `setImmediate`. Full example in lwc-recipes [here](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/fb170173c94c5edc4fba50a8b7e0cac38374b010/force-app/main/default/lwc/apexImperativeMethod/__tests__/apexImperativeMethod.test.js).

```
function flushPromises() {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    return new Promise((resolve) => setImmediate(resolve));
}

// in test case
return flushPromises().then(() => { ... });
```

Comment: thank you @trevorBliss. It works. However I am unable to understand the impact of having  "return new Promise((resolve) => setImmediate(resolve));" vs Promise.resolve().then() . Both are asyn right? Why is the latter not working?

Comment: @DeepSinghal The key here is that the setImmediate will only be resolved after *all* queued promises are run. Returning only a Promise without the setImmediate will queue up the Promise to run asynchronously, but may run before other microtasks. So if you trigger an action in your test that results in multiple async actions (Promises, component re-renders, etc) it may be necessary to use setImmediate to make sure they all complete first. I found this article super helpful in understanding microtasks: https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/

Comment: Thank you @TrevorBliss. It makes perfect sense to me.